# Correct use of the phrase "[XXX], but not only"

Tags: phrases, syntax

In an essay, if someone did something for various reasons, some (but not all) of them being historic reasons, is the following sentence correct:

"For various reasons--historic, but not only--he did this and that."

Comment: I don't find it at all idiomatic. 'Some of them historic'; 'Some, but not all, historic' etc. Beginning the phrase with the adjective makes the reader assume that it describes all the reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, I am correct in understanding that for instance "For various reasons--some, but not all, historic--he did this and that" is acceptable / idiomatic to you?

Comment: Yes I intended to convey that the versions I quoted were idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks. "Phrase" means "sentence" in my native language, hence some temporary confusion for me, that was not in your answer.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. The contrastive conjunction ***but*** is only "licensed" by the rather peculiar inversion of the parenthetical element, which would more naturally be expressed by *For various reasons--not only historic--he did this and that* (where there's no particular reason to include ***but*** anyway, but I wouldn't like to say it's necessarily "ungrammatical" to do so). I must be honest though - I have absolutely no idea what "historic" and "non-historic" reasons might mean in the cited context.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers. But wouldn't you agree that your version tends to insist more than Kate Bunting's on the fact that there are other reasons than historic? I read your version as "You should pay attention to the fact that not all these reasons are historic," whereas I read Kate Bunting's as "I inform you that some of these reasons are historic, although it should be noted that some of them are not."

Comment: As to the "historic reasons," the person uses certain words, a certain terminology, because he started doing so at a time when it was relevant and widespread, though it is now obsolete. But unless you--once more!--prove me wrong, I can't see why this would be relevant to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, or why. The cited text is both "comprehensible" ***and*** grammatical, but because it's not "idiomatic" (as both myself and Kate have said), there's little point in expecting us to agree on exactly what "nuance" might be intended by the choice of a "non-standard" construction. If a competent native speaker chooses to use a less common form of words, this is nearly always in order to convey something subtly different to the "standard" phrasing, but we'd need a ***very specific and complete context*** to identify that different nuance here.

Comment: Then _I_ don't understand. I do understand that my initial version is _not_ idiomatic and why. Then Kate gave an alternative, which she confirmed _is_ idiomatic: "some, but not all, historic." You then proposed yet another alternative: "not only historic," which I have no doubt is _also_ idiomatic, yet, it seemed to me that this last version put more emphasis on the fact that there were _other / non-historic reasons_ than Kate's, and asked for confirmation about the latter. I, in turn, am not sure what is unclear here. More context in my next comment.

Comment: As partially told in a previous comment, the context is that the person we are talking about uses a specific vocabulary 1/ Because he has always done so, starting at a time when it was relevant 2/ Also, maybe, because this vocabulary serves him and his achievements. I understand that context is important, and has impacts, but is one expected to give all this context for such a question?